# Connect data result to highchart

Tags: c#, javascript, highcharts

I try to connect my result data to highchart, I don't know how I can do this. 
My highchart code is in bottom.js which works. link to my fiddle  //jsfiddle.net/vbsvbs/4Rqgy

Now I have some results from a controller named exampleController.cs which I want to connect to my series. How can i connect them to my series?

my data looks like:

name: element1 
time: 20.06.2013, value: 12

time: 21.06.2013, value: 10

name: element2
time: 21.06.2013, value: 10

time: 22.06.2013, value: 11

Comment: I'm not seeing your fiddle

Comment: added link <http://jsfiddle.net/vbsvbs/4Rqgy>

Comment: That fiddle gives syntax errors on console when run

Comment: There is syntax error in code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Rqgy/1/ working example, but You need to have x/y parameters and time should be timestamp. Time in miliseconds (you can use i.e Date.UTC() ) and value should be y parameter, not "value"

Comment: thank for correcting, My x is a date and my y is basically the values of the elements. I get date values, name of the element and values from my DB and need to show them in a highchart